# Ver un PDF en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Deseo ver un `PDF` almacenado por un cliente, sin descargarlo, solo verlo. Usaba antes codigo en `PHP` antiguamente.

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile('file/cv/'.$_GET['archivo']);
?>
```

Tengo este código, donde puedo descargar el `PDF`

```
 <a href="{{asset('files/'.$post->file)}}"></a>
```

¿Debería agregar una función para que pueda ver el contenido del `PDF` en una pestaña?

Comment: y como diste solución a tu consulta... yo ando en las mismas.

Comment: Entonces como se hace cuando para preguntar a un usuario si alguien le ayudo en este portal, por que nadie respondió su pregunta.
Yo tengo hecha una pregunta del mismo tipo y tampoco nadie a respondido... que hago?

Comment: @JluisAntares, los iframe te serviran para hacer eso

Answer (score 4, accepted):

para visualizar el pdf lo puedes hacer de diferentes maneras.

Por ejemplo si quieres que el PDF se habrá en una nueva pestaña a tu etiqueta `<a>` le agregas el atributo "_blank" y su código quedaría así:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{asset('files/nombreDeTuPdf.pdf')}}">PDF</a>
```

Si quieres ver el pdf en la misma página lo puedes hacer con iframe:

```
<iframe width="400" height="400" src="{{asset('files/nombreDeTuPdf.pdf')}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Si quieres poder visualizarlo tambieén en dispositivos móviles Android lo puedes hacer mediante Google Drive Viewer que tiene la siguiente estructura(si no utilizas este viewer solo podrás descargar el pdf, pero no visualizarlo en la misma página):

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=UrlDeTuPDF&embedded=true"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
<iframe width="400" height="400" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf&embedded=true"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```